# AWS CDK - Cannot use tokens in construct ID - How do I dynamically name constructs based off the names of other constructs?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to create the same CW alarm/metrics for a number of DynamoDB tables in cdk, my instinct was to try to use a for loop to append the name of the DDB table to the CW alarm, but doing so generates the following error: Cannot use tokens in construct ID

It makes sense, because the token has yet to be evaluated so its just a placeholder value. But then what would a good alternative be to sequentially naming the alarms?

My usecase isn't that complicated I could just repeat the same code X times and tweak the name each time, but that seems like an incorrect approach.

I'm using the bellow code for inspiration, but I can't see what values I can call on that wouldn't trigger this error.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-cdk-developer-preview/

Comment: Have you tried using `Table.tableName` attribute? It's a simple `string`

Comment: That was my initial approach, but even that was triggering the error. My eventual solution was to have a hardcoded array that contained the half dozen or so tables I was interested in.

Comment: The key to the solution is to pass the object from which to get the ID from, as the `scope` of the alarm constructor ([ref](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6013#issuecomment-579870328)). The ID will include it, but then can access other IDs as name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the `id` or `uniqueId` of the table, something like:

```ts
for (const table of tables) {
  new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, `AlarmFor${table.node.id}`, ...); // or table.node.uniqueId
}
```

But a better pattern could be to create a `TableWithAlarm` construct and instantiate it multiple times in your stack.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the error when using `cdk.CfnOutput`, I used the same solution proposed by @jogold and it worked as a charm.

```
for (const lambdaDefinition of lambdaDefinitions) {
    const lambda = this.createLambda(lambdaDefinition);
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'output-' + lambda.node.id, {
        value: lambda.functionArn,
        exportName: lambdaDefinition.name
    });
}
```